# fastest way to get all svn file's latest commit revision with python

Tags: python, svn, revision, pysvn

Now I have a svn folder about 40000 files.I want to get all file's latest commit revision like this.

```
  res/image/1.png 27123

  res/map/101/1.png 14654
```

I have tried [pysvn](https://github.com/dsoprea/PySvn). And it has a function called list_recursive, it works but really slow.

So I want to know if there is a fast to way to get the result.

**EDIT**

Finally, I found the fastest way to complete this is calling "**svn list -v --recursive >> output.txt**", then use python to read the output.txt file data.

It's much faster than using the pysvn library.

Answer (score 0):

If a pure bash solution meets your requirments:

```
for i in `find . -type d -name .svn -prune -or -type f`; do
  echo "$i: " $(svn info $i 2>/dev/null | grep '^Last Changed Rev')
done
```

Brief explanation:

1. The find will search for all files (`-type f`) which are not under the .svn directory (`-prune`)
2. For each of them, `svn info` will gather the information you need and `grep` will filter out everything else.

According to [this](http://structure.usc.edu/svn/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html) (sorry, non reference found on redbeans version):

> ### Accesses Repository
>
> Only if operating on URLs

So it *should* be quite fast. Anyway I did this small test:

```
time (
  for i in `find . -type d -name .svn -prune -or -type f`; do
    echo "$i: " $(svn info $i 2>/dev/null | grep '^Last Changed Rev')
  done | wc
)
925    3325   87256

real    0m17.231s
user    0m2.648s
sys     0m1.416s
```

Unfortunately my working copy was on NFS, so timings could be totally unapplicable to you, bu you *could* expect up to 12 minutes for your case. Not sure if it is **fast** enough.